# Что делает конструкция (TypeA)TypeB в С#?

Tags: c#, ооп, наследование

Изучая исходники я нашёл такой код:

```
    Recipe silk = new Recipe(((Item)silk).itemID)
```

где класс Silk - наследует класс Item со свойством ItemID.

Так вот меня интересует конструкция (Item)silk, которая по моему предположению возвращает екземпляр родительского класса с дочернего. Как называется эта конструкция, что она на самом деле делает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Экземпляр класса, то есть объект как был `Silk`, так и остается. Никаких действий с объектом не производится.

Операция эта называется приведение типа, а если конкретнее - приведение типа к родителю или апкаст. Здесь изменяется только тип ссылки на объект.

Работает это все по принципу ООП "наследование".

Например, есть базовый класс и его наследник.

```cs
public class A { }
public class B : A { }
```

Например если создать

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
```

То можно сделать так (апкаст)

```
A ba = (A)b;
```

При этом возможна обратная операция (даункаст)

```cs
B bb = (B)ba;
```

А вот такая операция невозможна и выдаст `InvalidCastException` во время выполнения.

```cs
B ab = (B)a; // Ошибка
```

А все потому что здесь имеет значение реальный тип объекта, на который ссылается переменная. Повторюсь, что с самим объектом при этом ничего не происходит, он остается без изменений.