# Как реализованы классы в оперативной памяти И как в ней реализован принцип наследования классов?

Tags: c#, классы, реализация

Если кто то знает ответы на эти вопросы подскажите пожалуйста новичку.
Как в оперативной памяти реализуется принцип наследования классов как это работает и почему так можно делать?
Почему в с# объявляя массив объектов класса родителя мы можем каждый элемент массива объявить обьектом класса наследника?
К примеру

```
PointPlane[] points = new PointPlane[2]; 
points[2] = new PointSpace(1, 2, 3); 
points[3] = new PointSpace(4, -2, 5);
```

Да и воообще хотелось бы узнать как устроены классы в оперативной памяти?
Если кто нибудь знает и может объяснить или может кинуть ссылку на соответствующую литературу буду очень благодарен.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1342360/373567 реальный тип объекта задается при его создании и далее не изменяется

Comment: По поводу литературы - неувядающая классика жанра, Рихтер, CLR via C#, часть2 Designing Types. Хотя к прочтению рекомендуется вся книга полностью.