# Как преобразовать(конвертировать) возвращаемое значение double к float?

Tags: c#, float, double

```
float f_value = float.Parse(Math.Ceiling(56,3));
```

Выдает ошибку что нельзя конвертировать double в string.
Как привести можно получ значение double в float. В Convert нету метода преобразовать во float, только double и decimal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Этот код не может выдать ошибку конвертирования, так как он даже не скомпилируется. В коде числовые литералы с десятичной дробью пишутся через точку, а не через запятую - `56.3`. Будьте внимательны, когда выкладываете код в вопрос.

А вообще уберите `float.Parse`. Он предназначен для получения числа из строки, а у вас здесь вообще нет строк, о чём и говорит исключение.

```
float f_value = (float)Math.Ceiling(56.3);
```

Почитать

- [Явное приведение типов (casting)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions)
- [Преобразования базовых типов данных](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.2.php)
- [Что делает конструкция (TypeA)TypeB в С#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1342355/373567) (ООП)

Answer (score 1):

Функция Parse принимает на вход String, так что запись

```
loat f_value = float.Parse(Math.Ceiling(56.3));
```

просто ошибочна. Правильнее будет так:

```
float f_value = (float)Math.Ceiling(56.8);
```