# В чем разница между приведением и преобразование типов?

Tags: c#

Не могу понять

Правда, преобразование несовместимых типов все-таки может быть осуществлено путем приведения. Приведение типов, по существу, означает явное их преобразова­ние. (из книги)

Получается приведение и есть преобразование?

Comment: Эти два термина взаимозаменяемы. В каком-то конкретном языке может быть фиксирована определённая терминология, но я никогда их не различал толком. Идея одна и там и там: замена типа при сохранении (насколько это возможно) значения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Преобразование типов**

Значение типа `T1` изменяется так, что бы стать значением типа `T2`. Так например преобразование из `int` во `float` требует выделение битов под положение точки в значении. Или же при преобразовании `int` в `string` необходимо получить коды символов, которые бы отражали записанное значение в `int`.

**Приведение типов**

Объект с типом `T1` выражен через переменную `T2`, при этом структура объекта не меняется. Так например у нас имеется `T1 : T2`, где `T1` - дочерний элемент, а `T2` - родительский. Когда мы прописываем

```cs
T2 someVariable = new T1()
```

Мы выделяем в памяти место для нового типа `T1`, однако данные в этом типе устроены так, что бы этот тип можно было прочитать так же, как и `T2` не изменяя сами данные.

**Пример:**

Допустим у нас есть 2 класса:

```cs
class A {
  int aValue;
}

class B : A {
  int bValue
}
```

Тогда инициализация этих объектов в памяти будет выглядеть так:

```cs
var a = new A() // [..., int<aValue>, ...]

var b = new B() // [..., int<aValue>, int<bValue>, ...]
```

При этом `a` и `b` это указатели на первый элемент данных

Таким образом если мы сделаем

```cs
A b_as_a = b
```

То внутренняя структура объекта не изменится, но мы будем всё так же иметь доступ к первому значению `int<aValue>`, ведь его сдвиг относительно начала объекта для всех дочерних объектов будет одинаковый

Подробнее прочитать про даункаст (приведение дочернего типа к родительскому) можно [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1342360/373567)

*P. S.: Разумеется на практике всё работает немного сложнее, чем я описал сейчас, но этого достаточно что бы понять общую концепцию*

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1342360/373567

Comment: @aepot а вы что сразу то не пометили что это дубликат...

Comment: Это немного про другое вопрос. Можете добавить ссылку в свой ответ. Я уже ранее давал её автору вопроса.